# Add Unicode Meta tag to XPages for Polish Characters

Tags: unicode, utf-8, metadata, xpages, polish

I have the need to support different languages in my xpages. I have been informed that the Polish language have special characters which is part of the unicode character set. 
I have [read](http://webdesign.about.com/od/localization/l/blhtmlcodes-pl.htm) that I need to add the following to my xpages to support Polish

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

My question is if it is safe to add this meta tag to my xpages without breaking my xpages when using other languages. or should this Meta tag only be applied when using the polish language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be safe to add. I have an application that supports multi-languages and it uses UTF-8.

The easiest way to add this meta tag is to set it in Xsp Properties on the Page Generation tab. Just change from Server default to utf-8:

[image]